# Zipping contents of several directories in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory structure like this:

`root_folder 
           -->
              root_folder2
                       --> 
                         folder1 (has e.x 10files)
                         folder2 (has e.x 10files)
                         folder3 (has e.x 10files)`

How can I zip the contents of these folders (folder1, 2, 3) via a bash script.

Comment: Do you want a single archive containing all of them, or one for each?

Comment: @Panki one for each, so I'll have like folder1.zip, folder2.zip and folder3.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change directory within a sub-shell to obtain relative paths)

```
(cd root_folder/root_folder2; for i in ./folder? ; do  zip -vr $i $i; done;)
```

Comment: Yes, it works.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have only three folder to zip you could issue three different commands:

`find /root_folder/root_folder2/folder1 -print | zip folder1 -@`

`find /root_folder/root_folder2/folder2 -print | zip folder2 -@`

`find /root_folder/root_folder2/folder3 -print | zip folder3 -@`

See [zip(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) man page.